# I have a problem with duplicate data in the first sheet. Not connected together Is there a way to handle this?

Tags: excel, vba

The first sheet is a drop down list and the data is C:E.

I want to import the values from C:E in the first sheet
to another sheet based on the sheet name CELL B1:B10.

When I press the run button, the C:E data in each row will be Go and enter vertically in Column D in the destination sheet

and the selected part, A1:E10, will be copied below if there are duplicate data and duplicate values will be inserted again.

I have a problem with duplicate data in the first sheet.
Not connected together Is there a way to handle this? Thank you.

```
    Sub extracts data to sheet()
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
     Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
     Dim selectedOption As String
     Dim lastRow As Long
     Dim i As Long
     Dim sheetExists As Boolean
     Dim duplicateDict As Object
    
     ' Select and store the sheet containing the source data.
     Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEST")
    
     ' Create an object to store the same data.
     Set duplicateDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
     ' Loop through the Dropdown List in cells B2-B10.
     For i = 2 To 10 ' Change according to the size of your Dropdown List.
         ' Read value from Dropdown List
         selectedOption = sourceSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
        
         ' Check if the required sheet exists.
         sheetExists = False
         On Error Resume Next
         Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(selectedOption)
         On Error GoTo 0
        
         If Not targetSheet Is Nothing Then
             sheetExists = True
         End If
        
         ' If the sheet doesn't exist Display a warning message and cancel the operation.
         If Not sheetExists Then
             MsgBox "Execution unsuccessful. No items [" & selectedOption & "]"
             Exit Sub
         Else
             ' Checks if there is identical data in the range B2:B10.
             If duplicateDict.exists(selectedOption) Then
                 ' If there is identical data in the range B2:B10, copy the data A1:E10 from the duplicate destination sheet.
                 Dim duplicateTargetSheet As Worksheet
                 Set duplicateTargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(selectedOption)
                 duplicateTargetSheet.Range("A1:E10").Copy
                 lastRow = duplicateTargetSheet.Cells(duplicateTargetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                 duplicateTargetSheet.Cells(lastRow, "A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
                 Application.CutCopyMode = False
             Else
                 ' If the data is unique in the range B2:B10, copy the data from the range C2:E2 in the source sheet.
                 sourceSheet.Range("C" & i & ":E" & i).Copy
                
                 ' Place it in the destination sheet in column D:E in the first row.
                 targetSheet.Cells(1, "D").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
                 Application.CutCopyMode = False
                
                 ' Put the name of the duplicate sheet into the object to be checked in the next loop.
                 duplicateDict(selectedOption) = True
             End If
         End If
     Next i
    
     ' Clean the screen
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's your exptect output? A screenshot is helpful to understand your case.

Comment: I want the values to be inserted into column D in the sheet selected from the dropdown. If they are duplicates then the values will be changed to those in the first sheet.

Comment: What's `the selected part`? Why there are many `1` and several blank rows? I haven't seen the logic for it.

Comment: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 is to let you know that this is the end of the data which When you press the button, the information will be added below the end of this information because I want it to be COPY A1:E10.

Comment: On the page with the button there will be 2 repeated A. When the button is pressed the value will be sent 1 10 19 in A1:E10 and below 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 there will be new data like the one above but the value must be changed to 2 11 20.

Comment: Your code is not able to clarify what you want, as the question itself... Looking to the pictures you can deduce a logic algorithm, meaning to repeat the first occurrence of the row of each unique string in column B:B, in a way to let 10 rows and complete the number of respective first occurrence row elements. But in the above comment, to confuse us, you say "there will be new data like the one above but the value must be changed to 2 11 20". Do the pictures except the fist show **what you want** as they should, or  not? Do you want using each row componence? If so, was it difficult to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you accepted an answer, please also try the next code. It should be very fast, using arrays and working mostly in memory:

```
Sub extracts_data_to_sheet_()
 Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet, targetSheet As Worksheet, lastR As Long
 Dim arrS, arrTg, i As Long, j As Long, d As Long, k As Long, iStart As Long
 Dim key, dict As Object
 
 Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEST")
 lastR = sourceSheet.Range("B" & sourceSheet.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

 arrS = sourceSheet.Range("B2:E" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster processing
 
 'extract the unique keys/sheets name:
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrS): dict(arrS(i, 1)) = dict(arrS(i, 1)) + 1: Next i
 
 iStart = 1 'to memorize the next iteration start
 For Each key In dict.keys
    On Error Resume Next: Set targetSheet = Worksheets(key): On Error GoTo 0
    If Not targetSheet Is Nothing Then
        ReDim arrTg(1 To dict(key) * 10, 1 To 5) 'redim the necessary array to return in
        For i = iStart To iStart + dict(key) - 1
            k = k + 1
            arrTg(k, 1) = arrS(i, 1)
            arrTg(k, 4) = arrS(i, 2): k = k + 1
            arrTg(k, 4) = arrS(i, 3): k = k + 1
            arrTg(k, 4) = arrS(i, 4): k = k + 7
            For j = 1 To UBound(arrTg, 2)
                arrTg(k, j) = 1
            Next j
        Next i
        'Drop arrTg content at once:
        targetSheet.Range("A1").Resize(k, UBound(arrTg, 2)).Value2 = arrTg
        k = 0: iStart = i: Erase arrTg: Set targetSheet = Nothing
    Else
        k = 0: iStart = i + dict(key): If IsArray(arrTg) Then Erase arrTg: Set targetSheet = Nothing
        MsgBox "Execution unsuccessful. No any sheet named as """ & key & """."
    End If
 Next key
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

The next version is able to work (using array also) with unsorted values on B:B column. It creates a helper Sort column and fills it with numbers from 1 to last row number, then sort on B:B, processes the range as the above version (but placing the copied rows **after the last existing**), then resort the range on the helper column and clear its content:

```
Sub extracts_data_to_sheet()
 Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet, targetSheet As Worksheet, rng As Range, lastR As Long
 Dim arrS, arrTg, i As Long, j As Long, d As Long, k As Long, iStart As Long
 Dim key, dict As Object, arrSort
 
 Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEST")
 lastR = sourceSheet.Range("B" & sourceSheet.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 arrSort = Evaluate("ROW(1:" & lastR & ")")
 sourceSheet.Range("F2").Resize(lastR - 1, 1).Value2 = arrSort
 Set rng = sourceSheet.Range("B2:F" & lastR)
 
 rng.Sort key1:=sourceSheet.Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlNo
 
 arrS = sourceSheet.Range("B2:E" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster processing
 
 'extract the unique keys/sheets
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrS): dict(arrS(i, 1)) = dict(arrS(i, 1)) + 1: Next i
 
 iStart = 1 'to memorize the next iteration start
 For Each key In dict.keys
    On Error Resume Next: Set targetSheet = Worksheets(key): On Error GoTo 0
    If Not targetSheet Is Nothing Then
        ReDim arrTg(1 To dict(key) * 10, 1 To 5) 'redim the necessary array to return in
        For i = iStart To iStart + dict(key) - 1
            k = k + 1
            arrTg(k, 1) = arrS(i, 1)
            arrTg(k, 4) = arrS(i, 2): k = k + 1
            arrTg(k, 4) = arrS(i, 3): k = k + 1
            arrTg(k, 4) = arrS(i, 4): k = k + 7
            For j = 1 To UBound(arrTg, 2)
                arrTg(k, j) = 1
            Next j
        Next i
        'Drop arrTg content at once:
        lastR = targetSheet.Range("A" & targetSheet.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        targetSheet.Range("A" & lastR).Resize(k, UBound(arrTg, 2)).Value2 = arrTg
        k = 0: iStart = i: Erase arrTg: Set targetSheet = Nothing
    Else
        k = 0: iStart = i + dict(key): If IsArray(arrTg) Then Erase arrTg: Set targetSheet = Nothing
        MsgBox "Execution unsuccessful. No any sheet named as """ & key & """."
    End If
 Next key
 
 'Sort the range back, on the helper column and clear its content:
 rng.Sort key1:=sourceSheet.Range("F2"), Order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlNo
 rng.Columns(5).ClearContents
 
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Second **Edit**:

Please, also test the next code which also uses arrays, being very fast even for larger ranges. I only played with arrays in VBA. I commented each line, for somebody wanting to understand the way:

```
Sub extracts_data_to_sheet_Arrays_NoFilter()
 Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet, targetSheet As Worksheet, lastR As Long
 Dim arrS, arrArr, arrPos, genericArr, i As Long, j As Long, m As Long, k As Long
 Dim mtch, dict As Object
 
 Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEST")
 lastR = sourceSheet.Range("B" & sourceSheet.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

 arrS = sourceSheet.Range("B2:E" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster processing
 
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrS): dict(arrS(i, 1)) = dict(arrS(i, 1)) + 1: Next i
 
 ReDim arrArr(dict.count - 1) 'ReDim the array to keep each sheet necessary range array
 ReDim arrPos(dict.count - 1) 'ReDim the array keeping the number of B:B unique stings number of occurrences
 
 For i = 0 To UBound(arrArr) 'fill ArrArr with correctly dimensioned arrays, allso filling the the tenth row (with 1):
   ReDim genericArr(1 To dict.Items()(i) * 10, 1 To 5) 'specific arr for each B:B unique string number of occurrences
   For j = 10 To UBound(genericArr) Step 10
        For m = 1 To UBound(genericArr, 2)
            genericArr(j, m) = 1 'write i in the tenth array row for all columns
        Next m
    Next j
   arrArr(i) = genericArr: Erase genericArr 'place the specific array in the jagged ArrArr and errase it for the next use
 Next i

 For i = 1 To UBound(arrS) 'iterate between the array to be processed rows:
    mtch = Application.match(arrS(i, 1), dict.keys, 0) 'which key number/index is the found one
    arrPos(mtch - 1) = arrPos(mtch - 1) + 1: k = arrPos(mtch - 1) 'keep track of the necessary row number to be filled
    arrArr(mtch - 1)(k, 1) = arrS(i, 1)            'Write the key/sheet name
    arrArr(mtch - 1)(k, 4) = arrS(i, 2): k = k + 1 'write the first value from second column
    arrArr(mtch - 1)(k, 4) = arrS(i, 3): k = k + 1 'write the second value from the third column
    arrArr(mtch - 1)(k, 4) = arrS(i, 4): k = k + 7 'write the third value from fourth column
    
    arrPos(mtch - 1) = k: k = 0 'renitialize k
 Next i
        
 'Drop the ArrArr items value in the appropriate sheets:
 For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
    On Error Resume Next: Set targetSheet = Worksheets(dict.keys()(i)): On Error GoTo 0
    If Not targetSheet Is Nothing Then 'if sheet to return exists:
       lastR = targetSheet.Range("A" & targetSheet.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'the last where to paste
       targetSheet.Range("A" & lastR).Resize(arrPos(i), 5).Value2 = arrArr(i)    'drop the array content
       
       Set targetSheet = Nothing 'prepare it for the next iteration
    Else
        MsgBox "Execution unsuccessful. No any sheet named as """ & dict.keys()(i) & """."
    End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: but When I change the drop down list value, for example, there are many duplicate A, when I run the code in sheet A, why is data B displayed?

Comment: @Kao BeHappy This, probably means that I did not understand what you try doing... The above code processes all the range ("B2:E" & last row in B:B) from sheet "TEST" and sends all the same values from B:B in their appropriate worksheets, named as the values in B:B. Of course, **they must be sorted as you show the situation in your picture**... Do you want/need something else?

Comment: You can do this FaneDuru. In the first sheet, I changed the drop down list values to not line up. For example: A B C A B C A C B like this. I want the data to be sent to only the selected destination sheet. IN example, I select 3 values of A. Send these 3 rows of A to the destination sheet A. Do the same with B C. Thank you

Comment: @Kao BeHappy So, your question shows **a sorted range** and you want the code to work on **unsorted one**. Is this understanding correct? I can change the code to work in any way, but if you want it to be very fast, even for large ranges, it must be sorted. Now, I can place a sorting code to do that instead of you. Is that a problem? If yes, I can place a helper column and sort it back after processing. But when ask a question saying something and showing pictures, you will receive an answer based on what you show. I asked you in a comment about the question clarity and you did not answer it.

Comment: I have in mind another approach, without sorting, but using arrays. When I will be at home and find some time I will try putting it in practice.

Comment: @Kao BeHappy Please, also test the second **Edit**. I placed another version using only arrays, without being needed to sort and resort. Just playing with arrays in VBA...

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```vb
Sub extract_data()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim selectedOption As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sheetExists As Boolean
    ' Select and store the sheet containing the source data.
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEST")
    ' Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet
    ' Loop through the Dropdown List in cells B2-B10.
    For i = 2 To 10 ' Change according to the size of your Dropdown List.
        ' Read value from Dropdown List
        selectedOption = sourceSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
        ' Check if the required sheet exists.
        sheetExists = False
        On Error Resume Next
        Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(selectedOption)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not targetSheet Is Nothing Then
            sheetExists = True
        End If
        ' If the sheet doesn't exist Display a warning message and cancel the operation.
        If Not sheetExists Then
            MsgBox "Execution unsuccessful. No items [" & selectedOption & "]"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            With targetSheet
                If .Cells(1, 1) = "" Then 'for the 1st copy
                    lastRow = 1
                Else 
                    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                End If
                .Cells(lastRow, 1).Resize(10).Value = sourceSheet.Range("A1:A10").Value
                ' copy it over if you want to keep the format of sourceSheet
                ' sourceSheet.Range("A1:A10").Copy .Cells(lastRow, 1)
                .Cells(lastRow, "D").Resize(3, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(sourceSheet.Cells(i, 3).Resize(1, 3).Value)
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

---

Update: Assume the screenshot is what are you looking for, changing two lines to get it done.

```
Sub extract_data_v2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim selectedOption As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sheetExists As Boolean
    ' Select and store the sheet containing the source data.
'    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEST")
     Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet
    ' Loop through the Dropdown List in cells B2-B10.
    For i = 2 To 10 ' Change according to the size of your Dropdown List.
        ' Read value from Dropdown List
        selectedOption = sourceSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
        ' Check if the required sheet exists.
        sheetExists = False
        On Error Resume Next
        Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(selectedOption)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not targetSheet Is Nothing Then
            sheetExists = True
        End If
        ' If the sheet doesn't exist Display a warning message and cancel the operation.
        If Not sheetExists Then
            MsgBox "Execution unsuccessful. No items [" & selectedOption & "]"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            With targetSheet
                If .Cells(1, 1) = "" Then 'for the 1st copy
                    lastRow = 1
                Else
                    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                End If
                .Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = .Name
                ' copy it over if you want to keep the format of sourceSheet
                ' sourceSheet.Range("A1:A10").Copy .Cells(lastRow, 1)
                .Cells(lastRow, "D").Resize(3, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(sourceSheet.Cells(i, 3).Resize(1, 3).Value)
                .Cells(lastRow + 9, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = 1
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: .Cells(lastRow, 1).Resize(10).Value = sourceSheet.Range("A1:A10").Value
                ' copy it over if you want to keep the format of sourceSheet
                ' sourceSheet.Range("A1:A10").Copy .Cells(lastRow, 1)

Comment: Can I make it copy cells A1:E10 of the target sheet page?

Comment: If I have already made a pattern table

Comment: Of course you can `copy cells A1:E10 of the target sheet page`, but what is the destination of coping? `targetSheet.Range("A1:E10").Copy <<cell reference>>`. What's the pattern table?

Comment: I have updated the code with assuming the screenshot is what you are looking for.